# AdjustPan issue with keyboard during rotation

Tags: android

I have an issue with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` and soft keyboard.

In my app I have rotation support, every EditText has `EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI`

And every single activity marked as `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` can't persist the keyboard after rotation. I've already tried a lot of different solutions from SO but none of it helped. 
If replace `adjustPan` with, for instance, `adjustResize`, everything is working fine, but I need to replicate the same logic with `adjustPan` and it looks like some Android Platform issue. 
And one more problem, that initial state of activities should be without keyboard, so I can't use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateVisible"`

Any ideas how I can make the keyboard persistent without changing android:windowSoftInputMode and putting   `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`?